# Which operators are of interest in the theory of SDE's?

Tags: functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, operator-theory, stochastic-analysis

Is there a typical kind of operators of interest in the theory for SDE's? Is it possible to describe them in some way and what spaces do they usually act on?

Comment: Given a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ and a standard BM $(B_t)$ with its natural filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)$, we have that Ito integral $I$ itself is an isometry between a closed subspace of $ L^2([S,T] \times \Omega)$, $S, T \geq 0$, of progressively measurable processes (denoted by $L^2_p([S,T])$) and $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. Namely,$ \| I(f)\|_{L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})} = \| f\|_{L^2_p([S,T])}$. You may also want to study Markov and Feller semigroups associated with stochastic differential equations.

Comment: Pseudo-differential operators are also of interest because they pop up as generators of the semigroups associated with the solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes of operators mentioned in comments are Markov and Feller semigroups and also Pseudo-differential operators.